# Do carbon monoxide and graphene oxide react?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I want to know what happens if  $\ce{CO}$ and graphene oxide (GO) react.

Through the internet the reaction of GO with $\ce{H2O}$ is available but I did not find anything about carbon monoxide.

Comment: People: Please add better tags if appropriate.